# How to concatenate lines from the same paragraph in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a log file with the following lines:

vi test.log

```
    23 Jan 01:29:33.498/GLOBAL/ser: RECEIVED message from 91.x.x.x:33583:
    INVITE sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x SIP/2.0^M
    Supported: ^M
    Allow: INVITE, ACK, OPTIONS, CANCEL, BYE^M
    Contact: sip:131400xxxx@91.x.x.x:33583^M
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496^M
    Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6^M
    Cseq: 1 INVITE^M
    From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf^M
    ax-forwards: 70^M
    To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x^M
    Content-type: application/sdp^M
    Content-length: 127^M
    ^M
    v=0^M
    o=anonymous 1327282173 1327282173 IN IP4 91.x.x.x^M
    s=session^M
    c=IN IP4 91.x.x.x^M
    t=0 0^M
    m=audio 5856 RTP/AVP 0^M

    23 Jan 01:29:33.499/GLOBAL/ser: SENDING message to 91.x.x.x:33583:
    SIP/2.0 100 trying -- your call is important to us^M
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496^M
    Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6^M
    Cseq: 1 INVITE^M
    From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf^M
    To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x^M
    Server: SSP v2.0.84^M
    Content-Length: 0^M
    ^M
```

What I'd like to achieve is :

```
    23 Jan 01:29:33.498/GLOBAL/ser: RECEIVED message from 91.x.x.x:33583:|INVITE sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x SIP/2.0|Supported:|Allow: INVITE, ACK, OPTIONS, CANCEL, BYE|Contact: sip:1314007008@91.x.x.x:33583|Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496|Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6|Cseq: 1 INVITE|From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf|Max-forwards: 70|To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x|Content-type: application/sdp|Content-length: 127|v=0|o=anonymous 1327282173 1327282173 IN IP4 91.x.x.x|s=session|c=IN IP4 91.x.x.x|t=0 0|m=audio 5856 RTP/AVP 0
    23 Jan 01:29:33.499/GLOBAL/ser: SENDING message to 91.x.x.x:33583:|SIP/2.0 100 trying -- your call is important to us|Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496|Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6|Cseq: 1 INVITE|From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf|To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x|Server: SSP v2.0.84|Content-Length: 0
```

Basically all lines from the same paragraph (session) should be concatenated with "|" . A carriage return should then be added and next paragraph concatenated and so on. note that every new lines start with date & time.

So far I was only able to concatenate all the lines but unable to add the carriage return.. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Is it fair to say you want to replace $\n with | on lines that contains anything besides a $? And then just eliminate the lines that are only a $?

Comment: yes that's correct.. but the $ is actually invisible so it's just a carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following awk script to do that:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /^\s*$/) {print line; line="";} else line=line $0 "|"}' file.txt
```

This is assuming that after end of para always a blank line appears same as your example.

**Explanation:**

```
$0 ~ /^\s*$/ - to check if line is completely blank or only has white spaces
if block executes when blank line appears. It prints line var and resets line to ""
else block is concatenating line variable with the current line of file and a pipe
```

Comment: Actually the $ sign is an invisible character .. in Vi I've used :set list . in normal condition the $ doesn't show up

Comment: you're amazing! it works great! would you mind explaining what each section does for my own reference?

Comment: Glad that it worked out, added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (although you data is not clear):

```
sed '1{h;d};/^[123]\?[0-9] [JFMASOND].. ..:..:..\..../{:a;x;s/\s*\n\+/|/g;s/.$//p;d};H;$ba;d' file
23 Jan 01:29:33.498/GLOBAL/ser: RECEIVED message from 91.x.x.x:33583:|INVITE sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x SIP/2.0|Supported:|Allow: INVITE, ACK, OPTIONS, CANCEL, BYE|Contact: sip:131400xxxx@91.x.x.x:33583|Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496|Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6|Cseq: 1 INVITE|From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf|ax-forwards: 70|To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x|Content-type: application/sdp|Content-length: 127|v=0|o=anonymous 1327282173 1327282173 IN IP4 91.x.x.x|s=session|c=IN IP4 91.x.x.x|t=0 0|m=audio 5856 RTP/AVP 0
23 Jan 01:29:33.499/GLOBAL/ser: SENDING message to 91.x.x.x:33583:|SIP/2.0 100 trying -- your call is important to us|Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 91.x.x.x:33583;branch=z9hG4bKe65d47e555749b753faaf095c3256ec569bde77d37de66f62ff18bc40d492496|Call-id: ac755ea7e10821aa8174b2e5cd51d9e6|Cseq: 1 INVITE|From: sip:131400xxxx@sip.x;tag=5a541f1b2fd279cd0b8af3be3f67c7cf|To: sip:39329172xxxx@sip.x|Server: SSP v2.0.84|Content-Length: 0
```